# I can not focus this song on one of my ears with pydub

Tags: python, pycharm, pydub

I wrote this code with `pydub`. I want to make to different variables with the same song.
One song would just play in the left ear and one song would just play in the right ear.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment


src = "or_test.mp3"
dst1 = "mono_left.mp3"
dst2 = "mono_right.mp3"    # enter code here

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
    
mono_audios1 = sound1.split_to_mono()
mono_audios2 = sound2.split_to_mono()

mono_left = mono_audios1[1].export(dst1, format="mp3")
mono_right = mono_audios1[0].export(dst2, format="mp3")
```

When I run `mono_right` or `mono_left` the sound plays from both ears, but I don't want it like that.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

`sound2` and `mono_audios2` are not needed.
`mono_audios` indexes 0 and 1 - left and right - are inverted.
In  `AudioSegment.from_mp3` you also need to specify a format.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

src = "or_test.mp3"
dst1 = "mono_left.mp3"
dst2 = "mono_right.mp3"

stereo_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(src, format="mp3")
mono_audios = stereo_audio.split_to_mono()
 
mono_left = mono_audios[0].export(dst1, format="mp3")
mono_right = mono_audios[1].export(dst2, format="mp3")
```

If this doesn't work, then it's the audio player.

Comment: I listen it with my phone and it didn't work again